# Eve Exception: duplicate config_prefix "MONGO"`

Tags: flask, pymongo, eve

```
from views import app
    mongo = PyMongo(app)
    print mongo.db.activity.count()
```

Since I'm trying to use Pymongo count()

and it raises

```
File "Z:\Activities\modules.py", line 9, in set_id
    mongo = PyMongo(app)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_pymongo\__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, config_prefix)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_pymongo\__init__.py", line 122, in init_app
    raise Exception('duplicate config_prefix "%s"' % config_prefix)
Exception: duplicate config_prefix "MONGO"
```

But in fact I use default.
What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyMongo has already been initialized for you and is ready to be consumed at `app.data.driver`.

Try with the following:

```
mongo = app.data.driver
print mongo.db.activity.count()
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, except the above solution does not work:

AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'data'

It's possible this is an incompatibility between Flask-PyMongo 0.4.0 and pymongo 3.2..

Comment: @cacois it should work. I just tested it with v0.6.1 which is current stable. Where you are using it (I tested in a pre_GET callback function)? By the message you get I would guess that you are not using the Eve object.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. No, not using Eve, (I'm using Flask) but I am seeing the same error and misunderstood your guidance. I was assuming this error was a PyMongo issue, but from your response I'm guessing its an issue with the PyMongo-Flask module. Thanks for the reply!